# WinRT Access Violation Copying File in Local Storage

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

What would be a good way to update (replace) an image in local storage that is bound to an image control further up in the navigation stack.

To be more specific: I'm showing an image in page A (ViewProfile.xaml) with the image source bound to a property `ImageSource` in the ViewModel set using

```
ImageSource= "ms-appdata:///local/image.jpg";
```

In a second page B (EditProfile.xaml), I'd like to show the image again and give the user the option to change it, e.g. by replacing the file using

```
StorageFolder destinationFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
await profileImage.CopyAsync(destinationFolder, "image.jpg", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

The changed image would then be shown on page B and then page A when the user returns to it in the back stack.

The `CopyAsync()` fails with an unauthorized access violation. My understanding is that binding the image on the first page effectively locks the file so it cannot be changed. Since page A isn't actually doing anyting with the image other than showing it and perhaps reloading it after it is updated, there is no need to lock the file.

What is the right approach for solving this in a Windows 8.1 (WinRT) phone app?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the previous page's observablecollection to null to trigger a property changed event before making the change to the actual image file you are modifying.
Then you can reset the observablecollection back to the correct datasource to reset the datacontext accordingly.

Try that see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The controls in both pages are bound to individual properties of the corresponding (Prism) ViewModel. Property change events are fired by the setters. I have now set `ImageSource = null` in the `OnNavigatedFrom()` method of the first page's viewmodel, and back to the image file in `OnNavigatedTo()`. Still getting the unauthorized access exception. Did I apply your suggestion correctly?